# Change divs position

Tags: html, css

This is my simplified css code :

```html
    <div style="display:block;border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
     <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;">
      div1
     </div>
     <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;">
      div2
     </div>
     <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;">
      div3
     </div>
    </div>
```

It is displaying divs in this order : div1 div2 div3.

Is it possible to change their position to this order : div2 div1 div3 using only css?

Comment: You can use display flex and order or float div 2 left

Comment: you can give 'float:left' to div2

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have an example, or you can it as answer, if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is to float div 2 left:

```html
<div style="display:block;border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;">
        div1
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black; float:left">
        div2
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;">
        div3
    </div>
</div>
```

A more complex solution would be to make the container flex and use the order property

```html
    <div style="display:flex;border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;order:2;">
            div1
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;order:1;">
            div2
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;order:3;">
            div3
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add display:flex and change order css

Code

```
<div style="display:flex;border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
<div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;order: 2;">
    div1
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;order: 1;">
    div2
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;order: 3;">
    div3
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below workaround

```
   <style>
   .container { display: flex;}
   .div1 { order: 2}
   .div2 { order: 3}
   .div3 {order: 1}
   </style>

   <div class="container" style="display:block;border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
    <div class="div1" style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;">
        div1
    </div>
    <div class="div2" style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;">
        div2
    </div>
    <div class="div3" style="display:inline-block;width:32%;border:1px solid black;">
        div3
    </div>
   </div>
```